# how to override module-page-builder/view/frontend/layouts.xml

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides, page-layouts

i want to override module-page-builder/view/frontend/layouts.xml. please help me. i am not able to override.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can **overwrite** this file, but I can suggest workaround for do this.

You can create plugin for `\Magento\Framework\View\Model\PageLayout\Config\BuilderInterface::getPageLayoutsConfig` or define your custom preference for `\Magento\Framework\View\Model\PageLayout\Config\BuilderInterface` and control files to load.